# Count palindrome number that have total digits is divisible by 10

Tags: python, palindrome

How to count many palindrome number that have total digits is divisible by 10 from L to R `(1 <= L <= R <= 10^12)` in 0.5s?
My idea: generate palindrome number then count. But it is TLE.
Here is my code:

```py
def circle_num(x):
    t = 0
    for digit in str(x):
        t += int(digit)
    if t % 10 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def palinstr_evendig(half):
    return half + half[::-1]
def palinstr_odddig(h):
    return h + (h[::-1])[1:]
def num_palin_circle_num_1to(t, k):
    r = 0; j = 1
    while not int(palinstr_odddig(str(j))) > k:
        a = int(palinstr_evendig(str(j)))
        if (not a > k) and (not a < t) and (circle_num(a)):
            r += 1
        b = int(palinstr_odddig(str(j)))
        if (not b > k) and (not b < t) and (circle_num(b)):
            r += 1
        j += 1
    return r
s = input()
l, r = map(int, s.split())
print(num_palin_circle_num_1to(l, r))
```

And I don't have any idea to implement.
Python Language

Can anyone help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: Here's a trick: Only generate the first or last half of the number, and check if that is divisible by 5.

Comment: Oh, it also TLE. I have tried before.

Comment: Time limit just 0.5 second

Comment: And L, R up to 10^12

Comment: @Barmar.  That doesn't work if the number has an odd number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're counting the palindromes L ≤ x < R. If R is inclusive, just replace R with R + 1 below.

Suppose we had a function f(N) which counts the number of palindromes that fits your criteria such that 0 ≤ x < N.  Then we'd just need to calculate F(R) - F(L).   [Or f(R + 1) - f(L) is R is inclusive].

So let's look at even palindromes and odd palindromes.

- An even palindrome, say ABCDEEDCBA.  No matter what we have ABCD be, there are two values of E such that A+B+C+D+E is a multiple of 5.
- An odd palindrome, say ABCDEDCBA.  No matter what we have ABCD be, there is precisely one value of E (and it's even!) such that E + 2(A + B + C + D) is a multiple of 10.

Say we want to find f(314159).

- There is 1 palindrome of length 1 (0)
- There is 1 palindrome of length 2 (55)
- There are 9 palindromes of length 3.  (ABA, where 1 ≤ A ≤ 9)
- There are 18 = 9 x 2 palindromes of length 4. (ABBA, where 1 ≤ A ≤ 9)
- There are 90 palindromes of length 5. (ABCBA, 10 ≤ AB ≤ 99)
- In the range 100,000  ≤ x < 310,000, the palindromes are of the form ABCCBA, where (10 ≤ AB ≤ 30) and C can have one of two values.  So there are 21 x 2 of them.
- For the last digit, you have to look at them individually.  311113, 312213, and 313313  aren't multiples of ten.  314413 is both not a multiple of ten and too big.

So you can calculate f(n) in time linear to the number of digits in n.

---

Implementing this isn't that hard.  I'm going to assume that you're trying to calculate f(N), where N is an n-digit number.  The case of N < 100 is trivial (is 0 < N? is 55 < N?), so I'm going to assume n≥3.

How many 10-palindromes are there of length m, where 1 ≤ m < n?

- m = 1:  1
- m = 2:  1
- m odd and m > 2:  9 * 10 ** ((m - 3) // 2)
- m even and m > 2: 9 * 2 * 10 ** ((m - 4) // 2

How many 10-palindromes are there of length n that are less than N?
For length n.  Let's suppose N is AB...DED...BA if n is odd and AB...DEED...BA if n is even.

- For each value 10...0 ≤ ab...d < AB...D, there are 2 palindromes if n is even and 1 palindrome if n is odd. That's a subtraction and maybe a multiplication.
- Finally, for AB...D, there are 2 possibile values for E if n is even and 1 possible value if n is odd.  You have to check these two values to see if they are actually < N.

This is about twenty lines of code.

Comment: Can you implement it?

Comment: It's quite difficult to code with your idea.

Comment: It's actually not that difficult.